# R - Rplacing data in a column with other data in string format?

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe that contains the column event_place. 
Within is column, is 3500 rows of places where an event took place.

35 of these rows contains the value "Denver, Colorado". I want to rename these to simply "Colorado". They are dispersed across the 3500 rows.

How can I change rows that has the value "Denver, Colorado" to "Colorado"?

I have tried replaced row names and column names but I am unable to replace strings within the column with other strings.

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could this possibly help?

1. Converting column to a character:
   data$event_place <- as.character(data$event_place)
2. Replacing "Denver, Colorado" with "Colorado":
   data$event_place[data$event_place == "Denver, Colorado"] <- "Colorado"

Comment: This has worked. Thank you for your time, I appreciate it.

Comment: hi, can you please up vote my comment if my answer worked? I am a newbee too, trying to earn my points.

Comment: As I have less than 15 reputation, I'm unable to. I will when I get to that point!

Comment: Done! Thanks again.